# Access 2010 Query using IIF and ISERROR

Tags: sql, iif

I am trying to accomplish the following in an Access 2010 query

```
Select  
    UNIT, DATE, Sum(IIF(ISERROR(A),NULL,A)) AS DLP_PERCENTAGE  
From  
    tableA;
```

where

```
A = (ACT-BASE)/BASE
```

I get a generic OVERFLOW error.  I am missing something obvious.  I am trying to catch an error in the calculation and return NULL if an error exists or the result if no error.  I have to do it in a query.  Any ideas what I have overlooked?

Comment: Check your math. That is what will cause the overflow. That type of error may not be recoverable, hence the reason the iff isn't working.

Comment: I don't think IsError() is used to trap errors.  I believe it checks for error codes.

Comment: I had to do it this way  

    SUM((ACT-BASE)/IIF(BASE=0, 1, BASE)) AS DLP_PERCENTAGE

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM((ACT-BASE)/IIF(BASE=0, Null, BASE)) AS DLP_PERCENTAGE
```